# Call Expect_Call outside of Test_F

Tags: c++, googletest, encapsulation

I want to make several gtests which all have to have a connect in the beginning, and a disconnect in the end. The things that are tested in between vary. They look as such:

```
TEST_F(..., ...)
{
   // Connect - always the same
   EXPECT_CALL(...);
   ASSERT_TRUE(...);

   // different things happen
   EXPECT_CALL(...);
   EXPECT_CALL(...);
   ASSERT_TRUE(...);


   // Disconnect - always the same
   EXPECT_CALL(...);
   ASSERT_TRUE(...);
}
```

Hence, I would like to have something like this:

```
void connect()
{
   EXPECT_CALL(...);
   ASSERT_TRUE(...);
}

void disconnect()
{
   EXPECT_CALL(...);
   ASSERT_TRUE(...);
}

TEST_F(..., ...)
{
   connect();

   // different things happen
   EXPECT_CALL(...);
   EXPECT_CALL(...);
   ASSERT_TRUE(...);

   disconnect();
}
```

Is this possible? Are there smarter ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The other answer provides example how it's usually done - you'd likely put `connect()` in test fixture constructor and `disconnect()` in test fixture destructor. You may want to read [this section of documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.10.0/googletest/docs/primer.md#test-fixtures-using-the-same-data-configuration-for-multiple-tests-same-data-multiple-tests) to learn more.

To answer the question "Is this possible?" with some documentation (from [Advanced googletest Topics](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.10.0/googletest/docs/advanced.md)):

> You can use assertions in any C++ function. In particular, it doesn't have to be a method of the test fixture class. The one constraint is that assertions that generate a fatal failure (`FAIL*` and `ASSERT_*`) can only be used in `void`-returning functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example for setting up the mock object in the test fixture, which is instantiated once for each `TEST_F`:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class Object {
public:
  void someMethod();
};

class MockObject : public Object {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, someMethod, (), ());
};

class TestFixture : public testing::Test {

public:
  MockObject object;

  TestFixture() {
    std::cout << "Creating fixture." << std::endl;
    EXPECT_CALL(object, someMethod()).Times(1);
  }

  ~TestFixture() { std::cout << "Destroying fixture." << std::endl; }
};

TEST_F(TestFixture, SomeTest1) {
  std::cout << "Performing test 1." << std::endl;
  object.someMethod();
}

TEST_F(TestFixture, SomeTest2) {
  std::cout << "Performing test 2." << std::endl;
  object.someMethod();
}
```

The example can be compiled with:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtest gtest_main gmock) test.cpp
```

The output would look like this:

```
$ ./a.out 
Running main() from /build/gtest/src/googletest-release-1.10.0/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from TestFixture
[ RUN      ] TestFixture.SomeTest1
Creating fixture.
Performing test 1.
Destroying fixture.
[       OK ] TestFixture.SomeTest1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestFixture.SomeTest2
Creating fixture.
Performing test 2.
Destroying fixture.
[       OK ] TestFixture.SomeTest2 (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from TestFixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```